# Can I list the array data in the latest order in FlatList?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i want to diplay the array data in the latest order in FlatList.

when i console.log array, item for test

it shows like this

```
     array : [
   0: {id: 49, content: "부모1", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03- 
   12T13:57:53.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z", …}
   1: {id: 50, content: "부모2", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03- 
   12T13:57:57.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z", …}
   2: {id: 52, content: "하이", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03- 
   12T13:58:30.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z", …}
   3: {id: 53, content: "가나다", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03- 
   12T14:08:34.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z", …}
   length: 4
    ]
```

expected outputs are like this. depend on createdAt

```
    item: {id: 53, content: "가나다", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T14:08:34.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T08:47:33.000Z", …}
    item: {id: 52, content: "하이", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:58:30.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T08:47:33.000Z", …}
    item: {id: 50, content: "부모2", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:57:57.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T08:47:33.000Z", …}
    item: {id: 49, content: "부모1", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:57:53.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T08:47:33.000Z", …}
```

this is my code
(index.js)

```
    const Notification = () => {
      const {notification, replynotification} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
      const array = [
        ...notification,
        ...replynotification
      ]
        return (
        <FlatList
    data={array}
    keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <NotifiCard
      item={item}
      />
    )}
    />
        );
    };
```

(Notificard.js)

```
            const NotifiCard = ({item}) => {
                
                console.log("item:",item);
                return (
                <Container>
                    <Username>{item?.User?.nickname} </Username>
                    <Content>{item?.content}</Content>
                    
                </Container>
                );
            };

            export default NotifiCard;
```

how can i fix my code? if i want to list the item data in the latest order in FlatList?

Comment: You need to sort your data.

Comment: @HassanImam then how?....

Comment: Can you share complete array? Also, specify on which parameter you want your data to be sorted.

Comment: @HassanImam i updated my post can you check it? and i want to display item in the lastest order

Comment: Can you also share the expected output.

Comment: @HassanImam i posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string#localeCompare` to lexicographically sort the ISO 8601 date-time string.

```js
const data = [{id: 49, content: "부모1", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:57:53.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z"},{id: 50, content: "부모2", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:57:57.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z"},{id: 52, content: "하이", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T13:58:30.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z"}, {id: 53, content: "가나다", active: "1", createdAt: "2021-03-12T14:08:34.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-14T09:06:52.000Z"}];
data.sort((a,b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can i use your code in Notificard.js for item?

Comment: Use this code before at  `<FlatList data={array} .../>`, Just replace `array` with `array.sort(....)`

Comment: i posted my new answer is this code what you saying??

Comment: Yeah, it will work too.  You can use this `<FlatList data={array.slice().sort((a,b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt))} .../>`, as sort modify the original array.

Comment: thank you it much easier to look i learn my things thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I think this code works.

```
      const Notification = () => {
          
        const {notification, replynotification} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
        
        const array = [
          ...notification,
          ...replynotification
        ]

      const data = array

      data.sort((a,b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));


          return (
          <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <NotifiCard
        item={item}
        />
      )}
      />
          );
      };

      export default Notification;
```